# I want to Broadcast/stream video from my laptop using OBS to Agora & show that stream in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, azure, streaming, broadcast, agora.io

So I am trying to find a way to build a system in which Agora will take the video stream from my laptop using any streaming software i.e OBS and send this stream to agora server which i want to show in my Flutter app using a simple media player or Agora media player maybe. Can someone help me to just give me a few steps which i can use to build this live stream TV kinda thing in my app using agora (or some other better option Amazon IVS or Azure Media services). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume you have set up an Azure subscription etc

Open OBS

Select 'Streaming Endpoints' from the Media Services listing.

By default it may be stopped, select it and click start

Assuming you want to live stream it,
Select Live Streaming from the MEdia Services

Add live event and set it up, make sure you select the basic pass-through - no cloud encoding, select no for start lvie event to avoid billing then create it

Open the link to the event you created.

Add the video/audio source in OBS

Then in Controls panel, click "Start stream"

Switch to the link you opened/copied earlier and it should be live now.

From there just pull the stream into your Flutter App, not used flutter but basically set your video player/video source to the link of the event you just created.